# Webapp referencing external constants

Tags: java, web-applications, web-config, jndi

What would be the best way/practice to store an external constant value in a webapp? environment variable? application context? a JNDI lookup ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `init-param` in `web.xml` (universal, easy to modify, available only to your webapp).

JNDI is an option, too, but way of configuring it may change between servers.

Comment: But wouldn't the web.xml reside inside the war? what if it has to be changed (based on which env it is deployed on) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on the visibility of the params.

1. environment variable  : Enviornment variable if you want different
   processes to use those variable
2. application context  : If you want only your web appliction to use
   those variable
3. JNDI lookup : If you want multiple instances of your web app to use
   those variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *update* the value of this *constant*, JNDI can be a good option. See [How to Create Simple String and Primitive Resources in GlassFish](http://javahowto.blogspot.mx/2012/02/how-to-create-simple-string-and.html).